Why does the solution to $x'=x^3$ grow less fast than the solution to $x'=x^2$?
Reading through Schaeffer and Cains book on ODE's I made up the following example to test my understanding of a passage (see below).
Consider two IVP's:
$x'=x^2$ and $y' =y^3$.
Then by seperability $-1/x = t+C \iff x= \frac{1}{-C-t}$. Likewise $y = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{2(-C-t)}}$. For our example consider C=-1. Thus $x= \frac{1}{1-t}$ and $y=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2-2t}}=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-t}}/2$. On $(0,1)$ it seems that $x$ increases more quickly than $y$ (as seen from the derivative).
Schaeffer and Cain explain the 'explosion' of x by noting:

From the equation [x'=x^2], we see that x′ > 0, so the solution is always increasing. As x(t) grows, the equation
x′ = x^2 forces the solution to increase ever more quickly, and the growth accelerates
out of control in a finite time. It is instructive to compare [x'=x^2] with the linear
equation x′ = x, whose solutions also grow without bound but remain finite for all
time.

However for positive y', I would expect y' to increase much faster than x' and therefore a solution also to increase faster than x.
Why is this not the case?
Edit:
As @will-jagy points out: $x(0)=1 \implies C_x = -1$, and $y(0) = 1 \implies C_y = -1/2$ which does give a solution that blows up quicker in the interval.

$y$ does increase faster than $x$ when $y>1$. Plot $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ in desmos (here the $x$-axis represents $t$ which might be a bit confusing). Then, plot $y=1$ and observe that above that line $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ increases faster.

The passage introduces the "finite escape time" concept I think. As can be seen in the solution you provided, the differential equation $ x^{\prime} = x^2 $ has a finite escape time which goes to infinity in finite time, i.e., as $ t \rightarrow 1 $. It compares the solution with itself, "the solution increase ever more quickly as time goes by". On the other hand, linear equation goes to infinity in infinite time, i.e. as $ t \rightarrow \infty $.

if you begin $x(t)$  at $t=0, x(0) = 1$  and find   the two curves $x' = x^2$   and $x' = x^3$ for$t \geq 0,$ the cube grows more quickly

back to your letters, $x' = x^2$ with $x(0)= 1$   does give $x=\frac{1}{1-x}$  which blows up at $t=1.$   In comparison, $y' = y^3$  with $y(0)=1$  gives $y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t}}$ which blows up more quickly, at $t = \frac{1}{2}$
